# Regex match using one expression

Tags: regex, shell

Is there a way to match only the first two lines using one regular expression (not using the "or" matching like: `^cmd$|^cmd[[:space:]]+`)?

```
cmd
cmd -option
cmdanother
cmdanother -option
```

The word `cmdanother` can be anything starting with `cmd`.

P.S., thanks all for the answer. It works in the above case. However, if there is a line like:

```
cmd-anything
```

It is also selected (seems `-` is a word boundry). Is there a fix to this?

Comment: What command are you using to match? Is it `grep`?

Comment: Pedantically `-` is not a word boundary, the spot between the `d` and the `-` is the word boundary. And no, there's no "fix", the "word characters" are letters, numbers and underscore.

Answer (score 3):

if the input is exactly like what you have given, `\b` could work.

```
^cmd\b
```

just checking the beginning and ignore the ending should work.

However, the `\b` doesn't only match space, `:,.?...` would be matched as well. E.g lines `cmd:foo, cmd.foo ...` would be matched.

If they are not concerned, just take the `\b` one, otherwise, you do need  `|` (or) like:

```
^cmd( .*|$)
```

BRE: `^cmd\( .*\|$\)`

Comment: You might  use `^cmd([[:blank:]]|$)`

Answer (score 1):

You can **ditch regex** and use awk like this:

```
awk '$1 == "cmd"' file
cmd
cmd -option
```

Answer (score 0):

Use word boundary `\b`,

```
^cmd\b.*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iV8cC3/2)